# Why smooth projective curves are connected?

Tags: algebraic-curves

Why smooth projective curves are connected? I actually want to show that they are connected, compact, 2-manifolds.
(projective algebraic curves are zeros of a homogenous polynomial of three variables with complex coefficients in CP2. We will call a projective algebraic curve smooth in point p if its gradient is not zero at point p.)

Comment: What is your definition of a projective curve? My definition would not require them to be connected.

Comment: Can you show they are branched coverings of the projective line?

Comment: It depends on your definitions. Some authors require all varieties to be irreducible so curves are automatically irreducible and therefore connected. Without that convention, e.g. $\mathbb{P}^1 \sqcup \mathbb{P}^1$ is a disconnected smooth projective curve.

Comment: I think any smooth projective curves are irreducible due to Bezout's theorem.